# Component is wrapped in a Provider but this message appear: could not find react-redux context value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I would like to make a store to save id values, but I can't call the value in my home. the error appears: **could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a Provider**

the store:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    data: [
        684,
        683
    ],
}

function ids(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_ID':
            return {...state, data: [...state.data, action.id] };
            default:
                return state;
    }
}

const store = createStore(ids)

export default store;
```

the idlist:

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    
    function Idlist() {
        const ids = useSelector(state => state.data);
        return(
            [ids]
        )
    }
    
    export default Idlist;
```

and i'm calling it like this:

```
import Idlist from '../../components/Idlist';

function MainScreen() {

    return (
        <body>
            <main>
                <Idlist />
            </main>
        </body>
    )
}

export default MainScreen;
```

where the provider is:

```
import React from 'react'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store';
import Idlist from './components/Idlist';

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Idlist/>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

where de MainScreen is render:

```
import Signup from './Pages/Signup/Signup';
import MainScreen from './Pages/Home/MainScreen';

const routing = (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Signup} />
      <Route path="/MainScreen" component={MainScreen} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  routing,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

i have no idea what is wrong here

Comment: Could you show us where the provider is?

Comment: of course, i already edited the post

Comment: The IdList inside App looks fine, so i assume the error is being thrown by the IdList in MainScreen. Where is MainScreen rendered relative to App?

Comment: I believe the ```MainScreen``` component should be rendered inside the ```Provider``` , since ```IdList``` is rendered inside ```MainScreen``` .

Comment: I put now where is the MainScreen

Comment: put the MainScreen in Provider dont worked

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Provider` component to wrap `routing`.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import store from './store';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function Idlist() {
  const ids = useSelector((state: any) => state.data);
  console.log(ids);
  return <div>idlist</div>;
}

const Signup = () => <div>Signup</div>;
const MainScreen = () => (
  <div>
    <Idlist />
  </div>
);

const routing = (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Signup} />
      <Route path="/MainScreen" component={MainScreen} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>{routing}</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

`store.ts`:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  data: [684, 683],
};

function ids(state = INITIAL_STATE, action: any) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ID':
      return { ...state, data: [...state.data, action.id] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const store = createStore(ids);

export default store;
```